# Text Wrap not working for Telerik RadButtonElement

Tags: winforms, telerik

I am dynamically adding a button in Telerik RadListView. But the buttons are not wrapping the text.

Here is my code:

```
 this.radBtnProduct = new RadButtonElement();

 this.radBtnProduct.TextElement.Size = new Size(100,60); // .TextWrap = true;
 this.radBtnProduct.Location = new Point(0, 0);
 this.radBtnProduct.MinSize = new Size(100, 60);
 this.radBtnProduct.MinSize = new Size(100, 60);
 // wrapping
 this.radBtnProduct.TextWrap = true;
```

Any help is appreciated

EDIT:

I used this code

```
 this.radBtnProduct.Text = this.dataItem.Text.Replace(" ", "\n");
```

But am not sure if there are some issues with it

Answer (score 0):

By default RadButtonElement has its AutoSize turned on. You need to switch it off in order to make your size work. Try this:

```
   this.radBtnProduct = new RadButtonElement();
   this.radBtnProduct.AutoSize = false;
   this.radBtnProduct.Size = new Size(100, 60); // .TextWrap = true;
   this.radBtnProduct.TextWrap = true;
```